# Get JSON template of a cloudformation stack via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

When I run:

(AWS CLI)

`aws --profile dev cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name foo --output json`

I get:

```
{
    "Stacks": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:foo_region:fooaccid:stack/foo/foo", 
            "DriftInformation": {
                "StackDriftStatus": "NOT_CHECKED"
            }, 
            "Description": "foo description", 
            "Parameters": [
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "foovalue", 
                    "ParameterKey": "fookey"
                }, 
                {
                    "ParameterValue": "foovalue2", 
                    "ParameterKey": "fookey2"
                }, 
            ], 
            "Tags": [], 
            "EnableTerminationProtection": false, 
            "CreationTime": "2020-01-07T23:58:57.747Z", 
            "Capabilities": [
                "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
            ], 
            "StackName": "fooname", 
            "NotificationARNs": [], 
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
            "DisableRollback": false, 
            "RollbackConfiguration": {
                "RollbackTriggers": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that I don't get back the actual JSON template (that is actual code of the stack) of the stack.

Is there any way to get that via AWS CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [get-template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/get-template.html)

```
aws --profile dev cloudformation get-template --stack-name foo
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!